# In Java Regex - email validation, How to allow apostrophe before @ and not as first and last character before @ and not two consecutive apostrophe?

Tags: java, regex, apostrophe

**Regex Used**:

```java
EMAIL_VALID_REGEX = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"+"[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
```

Now i need to allow apostrophe before @ and also it should not allow apostrophe as first and last character and also two consecutive apostrophe before @.

Can someone modify the above regex to handle the mentioned scenarios and can you explain it?

**Valid emails**: test@gmail.com, test's@gmail.com, t@gmail [Even if single character is passed before, it is valid]
**Invalid emails**: 'test@gmail.com, test'@gmail.com, 'test'@gmail.com, test''s@gmail.com

Comment: Replace `(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@` with ``([.'’][_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@`` and it should suffice.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor Stribizew. it is working fine. Can you please explain me the regex posted  and how your solution is working. As basics, i know , this ^ indicates start , [] character class, () indicates group class, + indicates one or more characters , * indicates zero or more characters. kindly help me to understand it better. Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@` with `([.'’][_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@`:

```java
^[_A-Za-z0-9+-]+(?:[.'’][_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(?:\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$
```

Define in Java with

```java
EMAIL_VALID_REGEX = "^[_A-Za-z0-9+-]+(?:[.'’][_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(?:\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sVcXc0/1/)

The `[.'’]` part is a character class matching `.`, `'` or `’`.

The `^[_A-Za-z0-9+-]+(?:[.'’][_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@` part now matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[_A-Za-z0-9+-]+` - one or more underscores, hyphens, plus, letters or digits
- `(?:[.'’][_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `[.'’]` - `.`, `'` or `’`
  - `[_A-Za-z0-9+-]+` - one or more underscores, hyphens, plus, letters or digits
- `@` - a `@` char.

If there is a comma, or apostrophe, they will be allowed only in between the chars matched with the `[_A-Za-z0-9-]` character class, as both occurrences of `[_A-Za-z0-9-]` patterns on both ends of `[.'’]` is quantified with `+` (i.e. they require at least one char to match).

To apply the same restriction to `-`, `_` and `+`, use

```java
EMAIL_VALID_REGEX = "^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[+_.'’-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*@[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(?:\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$"
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sVcXc0/2).

Comment: Hi Wiktro, Thanks for the explanation. Actually we are already allowing  _-.(underscore, hyphen, dot) in our existing regex. So for this example test_-.s@gmail.com has to be failed. but it is showing as success since we are allowing _ in character class... Can you please let me know, how to include that condition [ie, _-.] and ' , if it comes together, then it has to fail

Comment: @Karthick Try [this variation](https://regex101.com/r/sVcXc0/2).

Comment: Wiktor, i tried with the regex shared in the link. Two scenarios are success, but it has to be failed . "ka_'r@gmail.com" , "ka-'r@gmail.com" . But this one is working fine. "ka.'r@gmail.com" . Since hyphen, underscore and dot are already allowed, we should not  allow consecutive special characters like _' or -'

Comment: @Karthick Those strings are [not matched](https://regex101.com/r/sVcXc0/3).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, i forgot to remove the _ from character class. Now it is working fine.